Tensor Flow Estimator Issues with DNNClassifier
I was trying to follow along with a freeCodeCamp tutorial for the Machine Learning program.  I am using Tensorflow currently and I am running the same exact code as the tutorial and I am getting no data output when I should be.
this is the code that I copied from the tutorial : https://www.freecodecamp.org/learn/machine-learning-with-python/tensorflow/core-learning-algorithms-building-the-model
from __future__ import absolute_import, division, print_function, unicode_literals

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib
from IPython.display import clear_output
from six.moves import urllib

import tensorflow.compat.v2.feature_column as fc

import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.compat.v1 import train

CSV_COLUMN_NAMES = ['SepalLength','SepalWidth','PetalLength','PetalWidth','Species']
SPECIES = ['Setosa','Versicolor','Virginica']

train_path = tf.keras.utils.get_file("iris_training.csv","https://storage.googleapis.com/download.tensorflow.org/data/iris_training.csv")
test_path = tf.keras.utils.get_file("iris_test.csv","https://storage.googleapis.com/download.tensorflow.org/data/iris_test.csv")

train = pd.read_csv(train_path, names=CSV_COLUMN_NAMES, header=0)
test = pd.read_csv(test_path, names=CSV_COLUMN_NAMES, header=0)


train_y = train.pop('Species')
test_y = test.pop('Species')



def input_fn(features, labels, training=True, batch_size=256):
  dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((dict(features), labels))

  if training:
      dataset = dataset.shuffle(1000).repeat()

  return dataset.batch(batch_size)



my_feature_columns = []
for key in train.keys():
  my_feature_columns.append(tf.feature_column.numeric_column(key=key))

classifier = tf.estimator.DNNClassifier(
  feature_columns=my_feature_columns,
  hidden_units=[30, 10],
  n_classes=3)


classifier.train(
    input_fn=lambda:input_fn(train, train_y, training=True),
    steps=5000)






and this is what I get on the line messsage:
WARNING:tensorflow:Using temporary folder as model directory: /tmp/tmpvy5r08vu
<tensorflow_estimator.python.estimator.canned.dnn.DNNClassifierV2 object at 0x793526ddefe0>
**ALSO for some reason the error message is no longer showing up, but it used to mention something about fixing the code with a global step and optimizer

hi @Chris Coble The warning you're seeing regarding the temporary folder is just TensorFlow's way of informing you that it's using a temporary directory to store the model checkpoints and other metadata during training.Insert print statements or use TensorFlow's tf.print function at various points in your code to see if the data is flowing through the pipeline as expected.Ensure that your input data is loaded correctly and has the expected format. You could print out some samples of the data to verify.
